# A Fermat's FLT look-like for matrices.

Tags: matrices, number-theory

I was wonderwing about a matrix equation (in some way similar to a very well known theorem :P).

Find all positive integers $n,m$ such that there exists $X$, $Y$, $Z$ matrices $n\times n$, non-singular, such that: $$X^m+Y^m=Z^m$$

Disclaimer: $X$, $Y$, $Z$ must have integer entries. Also, they may have an inverse which is not necessarily in $\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$.

I made some approachs (I don't know how to spoil, so if you want to think it yourself stop reading):

As my intuition says to me that there will always be solutions for $n>1$, then, it suffices to show there will be solutions for $n=2$ and $n=3$ (because then you can form a matrix composed by matrices $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ in its diagonal).

I showed that for all $m$ odd, and $n=2$ there is a solution.

Can someone give me a hand with the other cases? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @ Anthony:  would you mind showing us your solution for $m$ odd, $n = 2$?

Comment: Let 
$X=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & (2n+1)^n\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, $Y=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
(2n+1)^{n-1} & -1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $Z=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2n+1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

\\
Then $X^{2n+1}+Y^{2n+1}=Z^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Interesting!  Thank you!

Comment: If someone helps me with some of the other cases, it would be very good!

Comment: @ Anthony:  Well, I'm no expert at such matters, but if I come up with anything, I'll let you know; BUT . . . don't hold your breath waiting for me!  Thought-provoking question, though, +1!

Answer (score 9):

Ribenboim lists some known results in his book *13 Lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem*, e.g..

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Although these paper seems to be very interesting, I think it is not solving my problem (as far as we now know that FLT actually is true).

Comment: @Anthony Look at the results in the *other* direction.

Comment: Excuse me. Which of all of these results do you think that may be helpful? Thank you.

Comment: I gave a look into Ribenboim's book. At the beginning of this section he says (or I understand so) that Fermat's problem for matrices is not solved yet